# Downloading Embedded Resources in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm experiencing a typical issue.

The embedded resources are getting downloaded for one of my POST request for the first iteration, while they all are not when it runs for second iteration.

**Note:**
The first iteration, the POST request fires around 22 sample & sub samples.
The second iteration, it fires around 20 sample & sub samples. The rest 2 sub samples not gets downloaded.

Any idea, anyone can please share.

Answer (score 7):

Any chance you are using [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)? When you configure JMeter to download embedded resources and have cache manager enabled JMeter acts like a browser and retrieves matching embedded resources ***only once**, on subsequent requests they are being returned from cache. Actually this is how your test should be normally behaving as representing real users as close as possible is the main goal of the well-behaved load test

1. Without Cache Manager

   [image: Without Cache Manager]
2. With Cache Manager

   [image: With Cache Manager]

If this is the case you can tick "Clear cache each iteration" box in the HTTP Cache Manager to overcome the default behavior. If not - maybe your application uses its own caching implementation, this is something you need to check with the developers.

Check out [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more information on mimicking real users in JMeter web test

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dmitri, the issue got resolved. 

Actually, the issue was not with Cookie or Cache configurations. My script was having issue with functional parametrization. I was using SSN which has to be unique, now it's all working fine.