# JMeter Add Think Time to children feature

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter when I right click Thread/Controller I have an option: `Add Think Time to children` feature , when I click on it I get after every Sampler `Test Action` Pause with `Uniform Random Timer` with Random Delay 100 and Constant Delay 1000.

I didn't find in documentation any reference to it and why/how it should be used.
Is it configurable and how? is there a special case for it or should it be used for loading best practice ?

Also you can add several times think times I'm not sure is it on purpose (add more delays after request)

**EDIT**

Configurable using jmeter.properties:

```
# Default implementation that create the Timer structure to add to Test Plan
# Implementation of interface org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.thinktime.ThinkTimeCreator
#think_time_creator.impl=org.apache.jmeter.thinktime.DefaultThinkTimeCreator

# Default Timer GUI class added to Test Plan by DefaultThinkTimeCreator
#think_time_creator.default_timer_implementation=org.apache.jmeter.timers.gui.UniformRandomTimerGui

# Default constant pause of Timer 
#think_time_creator.default_constant_pause=1000

# Default range pause of Timer
#think_time_creator.default_range=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is made to simplify addition of Think Times, the way it adds them to plan lead to pause between every sampler while if you just add a Timer it will be scoped and thus be applied before all samplers in scope.

As it's a helper, it adds default Pause of 1 second that are configurable by tuning the properties you have mentioned and which are documented :-) :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#timer

You can adjust:

- The type of Timers you want to create
- The constant and variable pause range

You can even create your own class that would work differently.

Comment: If question is about how timers work,  I really meant before , see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers If about the Add Think time feature, then pause really apply where the timer is set and only there which gives more control

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to web applications load testing the idea is to represent a real user sitting in front of computer using a real browser as close as possible.

Well-behaved JMeter test needs to mimic this real user with all its stuff like:

- [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
- [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- [embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994494/downloading-embedded-resources-in-jmeter)
- [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
- etc.

The purpose of using [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) in JMeter tests is simulating real users "think times". Users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations, fill forms, type comments, even clicking on a button or link takes some time. So if you are testing if your web application supports X users each JMeter thread must act like a real user so you need to add **reasonable** think times using Timers. There is no "best practice" or "known good values", it depends only on your web application specifics. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for more details.