# JMeter - execute requests according to given millisecond offset

Tags: jmeter

For a JMeter load test, I'd like to replay what we call a 'playbook', which has a form similar to this:

```
  offset ms | request
  --------------------------
          0 | http://localhost/request1
          7 | http://localhost/request2
         12 | http://localhost/request3
         25 | http://localhost/request4
        ... | ...
```

Where '0' is the start time of the test, and each request should be fired exactly x milliseconds after that, as given in the first column, irrespective of how long the single requests take.

What I want to avoid is the *regular* way JMeter works, where each thread basically fires one request after the other.

Background: We already have a tool which creates this sort of *playbook*, and it is a very realistic way of simulating user behavior. We are now evaluating if we can use JMeter to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter this is similar to [Think time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542116/jmeter-add-think-time-to-children-feature),

You can add after each request similar to Think time a Test Action after each request and under it a Timer as a [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) with Random = 0 and in your case:

- After first request 7000 Constant Delay Offset
- After second request 5000 Constant Delay Offset
- After third request 13000 Constant Delay Offset